# How to sink rvalue in a path where it's not used

Tags: c++11, rvalue-reference, rvalue

When a function takes an rvalue reference which it doesn't use in some branches, what should it do with the rvalue to maintain the semantic correctness of it's signature and to be consistent about the ownership of the data. Considering the sample code below:

```
#include <memory>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

struct Packet {};

std::list<std::unique_ptr<Packet>> queue;

void EnQueue(bool condition, std::unique_ptr<Packet> &&pkt) {
    if (condition) queue.push_back(std::move(pkt));
    else /* How to consume the pkt? */;
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Packet> upkt1(new Packet());
    std::unique_ptr<Packet> upkt2(new Packet());

    EnQueue(true, std::move(upkt1));
    EnQueue(false, std::move(upkt2));

    std::cout << "raw ptr1: " << upkt1.get() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "raw ptr2: " << upkt2.get() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The signature of the Enqueue function indicates that it will take ownership of the data passed to it but this is only true if it hits the **if** path, instead if it hits the **else** path the function effectively doesn't use the rvalue and the ownership is returned back to the caller, which is illustrated by the fact that upkt2.get is **not** NULL after returning from the function. The net effect is that the behaviour of EnQueue is inconsistent with it's signature.

The question now is - whether this is an acceptable behaviour or should the EnQueue function be changed to be consistent, if so how?

Comment: Just take the `unique_ptr` by value.

Answer (score 0):

I see three ways of dealing with this.

1. Document that after the function exits, "`pkt` is left in a valid, but unspecified state." That way, the caller cannot assume anything about the parameter afterwards; if they *need* it cleared no matter what, they can do it explicitly. If they don't, they will not pay for any internal cleanup they would not use.
2. If you want to make the signature 100% clear on accepting ownership, just take `pkt` by value instead of rvalue reference (as suggested by @Quentin in comments).
3. Construct a temporary from `pkt`:

   ```
   if (condition) queue.push_back(std::move(pkt));
   else auto sink(std::move(pkt));
   ```